# Asp.net GridView Headertext aligment problem with the Column text

Tags: asp.net

In my `GridView` the `Headertext` is aligned to left and `itemstyle` is aligned to left but the header is not exactly aligned to left. It leaves some space before.

Saml code: `<asp:BoundField DataField="COMPANY_TYPE" SortExpression="Company_Type" HeaderText="Company Type" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"/>`

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your padding on the `<th>` elements in the header is larger than the `<td>` elements in the item rows. Use Firebug (or equivalent) to check if something in your css is affecting it. I would also look into the source of the page to verify that there is not any extra whitespace or anything before your column headers.

Answer (score 1):

In the column section where you set the fields add this

```
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
```

for example:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.HeaderStyle {
    text-align: Left
}


<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="TestAlign" ShowFooter="True"
     DataSourceID="testDataSource" Width="600"
     HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderStyle">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="left" HeaderText="-left-"
             HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderStyle" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```